# uiview hidden problems in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

if i was hidden the image view.. run time error was occured or
imgView.hidden=YES;
imgView.hidden=NO;

this two lines are got a runtime error.. how to handle this..... or

imgView.image= any one image
imgView.image=nil

this two lines also got a run time error is "exec-bad access" or "debugging is termnated"

how to handle this, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you create outlet for imageview or not?

If it's not outlet then you have to initialize the imageview

Comment: i accept this answer but i have manualy create a uiimage view.. so please help me